# @file_get_contents() and curl failed to get page contents, I need alternate code

Tags: php, web-scraping

some sites are blocking @file_get_contents and the curl code also. I need code(PHP) that circumvents that problem. I only need to get the page contents so I can extract the title.

Comment: if sites are blocking that, it's because they don't want you to. don't violate their policies.

Comment: @Mat: If sites want to have a say in the User Agent of their visitors and the (legal) usage they will do of the output they should be iPhone applications or something else, not web sites on the open internet. Beside blocking non-common UAs is what produce the current user agent mess forced on the browsers for compatibility with all theses crappy websites.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the user agent string to emulate a "real" browser:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/4.0');
```